# Django urls.py config gives page 404

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a very simple Django installation with one app, but I cannot get the `urls.py` configured correctly. It's strange, because I have the same config in another application, which works perfectly.

`urls.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('subscribe/', include('newsletter.urls')),
    path('subscription-confirmation/<str:key>/', include('newsletter.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

APP `urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path
from newsletter.views import subscribe, subscription_conf

urlpatterns = [
    path('subscribe/', subscribe),
    path('subscription-confirmation/<str:key>/', subscription_conf),
]
```

Error in browser:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe/
Using the URLconf defined in backoffice.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. subscribe/ subscribe/
2. subscribe/ subscription-confirmation/<str:key>/
3. subscription-confirmation/<str:key>/
4. admin/

The current path, subscribe/, didn’t match any of these.
```

I'm pulling my hair out with this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to access the page

Comment: You have 'subscribe' twice in your pattern: in the urls.py and again in the included app/urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the page is really not found. At least nothing points to the URL which you called.

You requested: http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe/

Which is looking for: `subscribe/`

But you do not have that, since you also included the app's url in that line. So you only have http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe/subscribe

I think you should:

1. In your project's `urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('newsletter.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

2. In your app's `urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('subscribe/', subscribe),
    path('subscription-confirmation/<str:key>/', subscription_conf),
]
```